# Matching files in a directory and checking

Tags: bash, shell, filenames

I have files in a directory (/home/user/example) that I need to verify and match. Each file has a control and data file. I want to check if for each file there is a corresponding file of the other. For example, if example.ctl has a match with example.out or example.out has a corresponding file with example.ctl.

I had written a nested for loop and  with many if else statements. But this seemed to be far too complex for a basic check like this. I wanted to see if anyone had a better solution.

Example files in directory:

```
example.ctl
example.out  
example_1.ctl
example_1.out  
example_2.ctl
example_2.out
```

Comment: Any bit of chance to see your actual code 'for loop' ???

Comment: @don_crissti Upvoted your comment by mistake; it's not a duplicate because the other question said "there are .A files without .B files, but no .B files without .A files."

Comment: @l0b0  - all right... though the Q here is vague. OP, what is the expected output here ? List unpaired file names regardless of their extension ?

Comment: That would be my guess

Comment: Yes that's what I'm trying to accomplish

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### First variant

It iterates through all filenames and check each file, does it has a pair or not and prints a corresponding message.

```
for i in *; do
    base=${i%.*}
    if [ -e "${base}.out" -a -e "${base}.ctl" ]; then
        printf 'file "%s" has a pair\n' "$i"
    else
        printf 'file "%s" has not a pair\n' "$i"
    fi  
done
```

#### Second variant

It iterates only through `.ctl` files and check does the current `.ctl` file have a pair - the `.out` file. So, it prints only paired files, omitting the rest - unpaired files.

```
for i in *.ctl; do
    base=${i%.*}
    if [ -e "${base}.out" ]; then
        printf 'file "%s" has a pair "%s"\n' "$i" "${base}.out"
    fi
done
```

Answer (score 2):

```
comm <(basename -a -s.ctl *.ctl | sort) <(basename -a -s.out *.out | sort)
```

See `comm(1)`, espacially the flags `-12` will list only files with both suffixes.

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to detect missing .ctl *and* .out files, so you need to check both ways. An easy way to do this (if your file names contain no special characters, including whitespace, and contain only a single dot) is to

1. find all files with `find . -type f`,
2. remove the extension from each of them with `cut --delimiter=. --fields=1`,
3. `sort --unique` to remove duplicates,
4. loop through them with `while read name`, and finally
5. check if each of the files exist with `[[ -e "${name}.ctl" ]] || echo "${name}.ctl" >&2` and the same for .out.

Answer (score 0):

You can loop across the files and derive the expected filenames for the Output and Control files. Once you've done that you can check that both exist:

```
for item in *.out *.ctl
do
    base="${item%???}"
    out="$base.out" ctl="$base.ctl"
    [ -f "$out" -a ! -f "$ctl" ] && echo "$out is missing $ctl" >&2
    [ -f "$ctl" -a ! -f "$out" ] && echo "$ctl is missing $out" >&2
done
```