# Matching filenames within a directory

Tags: bash

I have control files which inside will have a count of the expected records in the csv file. Each csv file has an accompany ctl file. My question is what is the best way to match the files with it's counterpart? I think there must be a better way than nested for loops. This is Bash Shellscript.

example content of ctl file:

```
101
```

Directory where files are:

```
/home/user/example
```

Example file names:

```
project_example_1998-01-01.ctl
project_example_1998-01-01.csv
project_example_1998-02-09.ctl
project_example_1998-02-09.csv
project_example_1999-08-09.ctl
project_example_1999-08-09.csv
project_example_2000-02-09.ctl
project_example_2000-02-09.csv
```

Comment: Do you just want to see unmatched files of either "extension", or do you want to check .csv files' record count against the number in the respective .ctl file?

Comment: What does it mean exactly: "to match the files with it's counterpart"?

Comment: Why are you asking [exactly the same question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/432643/100397) again?

Comment: I had originally thought about it as two separate problems as in identifying the files that didn't have a corresponding file and then matching the counts of files. Your correct the variants in the prior answer were able to solve the problem.